# Install kartik/yii-grid without updating other widget

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

I want to use kartik yii-grid to make editable grid. But when i am trying to install it though composer using following command

```
php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-grid "@dev"
```

But it will update so many thing from my vendor also even yii2 framework bootstrap. Can any one suggest me to install this widget without effecting my other vendor stuff?

Comment: take a copy of composer.json and delete it.. after installing grid put old composer.json as it ireplaced with newely created

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
"kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev"
```

to the require section of your composer.json file.

Then run:

```
php composer.phar update kartik-v/yii2-grid
```

Installing or updating a single dependency is outlined in composers documentation [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies).

Comment: I have already follow this steps. But still they update their dependent stuffs.

Comment: it is because yor composer.json contains the information about other stuffs. so just create new.

Comment: i think this will update other stuff if the "kartik-v/yii2-grid" depends on other package that is now installed in lower version than required

Answer (score 0):

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions

Composer installs what is specified in composer.json file. If you want all of the dependencies are never updated - in composer.json specify the exact version of the package, then the composer would never try to update it.
So that you are trying to bypass the upgrade of packages during the installation - this is a bad decision, you should have the right composer.json, rather than trying to deceive composer

=====

Also from https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require
You may help --no-update key, but I'm not sure

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check it out with your reference link document options. And then get back you.